# Unidentified network in Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking

I am setting up a simple Home network for education purpose. We have installed Windows 10 on of the computer and configured with IP address 192.168.0.X Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0. And connected LAN cable to one 8 port switch and connected another computer with a LAN cable to this switch.

I am getting "Unidentified network" message and I don't have any Security software installed. And in Device Manager no missing drivers present and I checked network drivers installed correctly.

I am using normal LAN (RJ45) cable, do I need to use some other cable, if I connect the machine with broadband cable which is connected to modem, there is no issue, the Local Area Connection is showing "Enabled" and Internet is working fine.

Switch is working fine. Any help would be appreciated to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the "Unidentified network" message?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Windows reporting as an "unidentified network" is no actual problem.

- Computer 1  settings ip : 192.168.1.1 subnet : 255.255.255.0
- Computer 2 settings ip: 192.168.1.2 subnet : 255.255.255.0

To be sure you actually have connection between the two machines

1. Start -> Type cmd, wait, press enter.
2. On the new console that opened  type "ping 192.168.1.x" x being the
   opposite machine from where you do this.

If it reports anything except time-out or disconnected media, you have communication.
As a control case, for expected results replicate the experience on a computer with internet access but type "ping 8.8.8.8" 8.8.8.8 is the address for google's dns servers.

Comment: Thanks! actually another computer is just connected to switch and its powered off. I am making the 1st computer as DHCP server and 2nd computer should get IP address at the time of booting once powered on from DHCP server. I will try and let you know whether its working or not.